# How to enable cross-chain asset transfers to a parachain?

Tags: parachain, xcm, xcmp, hrmp, orml-xtokens

This is a question about XCM.
Do I just need to add `orml_xtokens` dependency to a parachain to allow transferring assets to another chain?

Comment: Could you clarify what cross-chain transfer function means? As I read it, it sounds like you want to enable sending assets cross-chain? Or do you mean you want to enable XCM execution and processing altogether?

Comment: Sorry, More like the former, I'm not sure what the latter does.

Comment: My question is more like, should I just introduce orml_xtokns and not worry about anything else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [ORML Xtokens pallet](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/tree/master/xtokens) is just the first step, as you try to configure it in your chain, you'll quickly see that it requires an `XcmExecutor` configuration item, which the [`xcm-executor`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/8ef830db9a009fdf4cf5092ebaf14371d27a9a4c/xcm/xcm-executor/src/lib.rs#L44) module offers a default implementation of.

The problem next is that the default `XcmExecutor` itself also requires configuration, and one of the items for the `XcmConfig` is to specify the `XcmSender`. This is where you'll need to include pallets that implement the proper message passing protocol. Depending on who you want to send your XCM to, you'll either need to include the [XCMP queue pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/tree/master/pallets/xcmp-queue) if you're sending to a sibling parachain, or include the [parachain system pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/tree/master/pallets/parachain-system) if you're sending to the relay chain.

You may also want to take a look at [my answer here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/38/104) to decide which asset transfer model that you'd like to pick for your chain.

Comment: Thanks! One thing I'm a little confused about is the difference between `XCMP` and `HRMP`. I can understand the conceptual difference, but isn't `XCMP` not developed yet? `xcmp-queue` is now `HRMP` content?

Comment: HRMP is in fact XCMP-lite, a stop-gap solution before XCMP is complete and ready. As I understand it, HRMP uses the relay chain as an inbox/outbox message storage, whereas XCMP will only be using the relay chain as a router of messages and nothing else. See https://w3f.github.io/parachain-implementers-guide/messaging.html#cross-chain-message-passing for more information.