# Non Fungible Token XCM transfer documentation

Tags: parachain, xcm, nft

I am very interested in any documentation with examples of how to send `NFTs` from one `parachain` to another with `XCM`.

Answer (score 10):

This is not quite possible on XCM V2, but will be very soon once V3 gets into the runtime. The PR for adding non-fungibles is here: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/4950

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the PR that @joepetrowski mentioned, you may want to check out [my answer here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-can-i-transfer-assets-using-xcm) to decide how exactly you would like to transfer your NFTs, as NFT transfers also use the same models as fungible token transfers, namely reserve asset transfer and teleportation.