# What is the difference between `limitTeleportAssets` and `reserverTransferAssets`?

Tags: xcm

What does `limitTeleportAssets` do?

How is it different than `reserverTransferAssets`?

Comment: There's quite a lot of documentation in the XCM pallet which should answer this comprehensively. See these two functions specifically:  https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/0a34022e31c85001f871bb4067b7d5f5cab91207/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L508-L523 and https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/0a34022e31c85001f871bb4067b7d5f5cab91207/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L716-L732 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both execute the same logic but the limited one can add a weight limit to the execution.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/0a34022e31c85001f871bb4067b7d5f5cab91207/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L825

Answer (score 4):

This is a dupe of:
[How can I transfer assets using XCM?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-can-i-transfer-assets-using-xcm/38#38) , but the TL/DR is:

- Teleport Assets: They mint new assets on the dest chain and TRUST that the source chain really did burn them. ([Diagram](https://www.figma.com/file/EIebkEmJro91Q33HH9V2p2/XCM-Teleport?node-id=0%3A1))
- Reserve Transfer: Some assets on an agreed reserve chain (E.g. statemint) are moved from your chain's account to their chain's account and then their chain will likely mint the beneficiary some IOUs on the dest chain to represent the money (that actually never leaves the reserve chain). ([Diagram](https://www.figma.com/file/9WoqPIRBv2zh23yt8LGU0c/XCM-Transfer-Reserve-Asset?node-id=0%3A1))

Comment: (The diagrams will improve over time as I get better with figment jam)

Answer (score 1):

The main difference should be `reserve` vs `Teleport`. Reserve transfer require asset backup in sovereign account while Teleport not