# XCM cross-chain transfer error FailedToTransactAsset("InsufficientBalance")?

Tags: xcm, orml-xtokens, cross-chain

development env: one relaychain, two parachain

1. relaychain rococo-local, tokenSymbol: ROC, Alice 1MROC
2. parachain local 2000, tokenSymbol: KK, Alice 1MKK
3. parachain local 2102, tokenSymbol: DD, Alice 1MDD
4. HRMP bi-direction channel opened between 2000 and 2102

both parachain has orml pallets:

- xcm
- xcm-support
- xtokens
- tokens
- currencies

This error FailedToTransactAsset("InsufficientBalance") occurs when para2000 transfer relaychain ROC to para2102(also error para2000 transfer native KK to para2102). XCM execute detail as follows:
[image]

Did I miss something?
The "InsufficientBalance" means Alice's relaychain account ROC is not enough or Alice's parachain account ROC not enough?
Should I config the orml tokens balances in spec?

Reference:

- https://wiki.acala.network/build/development-guide/composable-chains/open-hrmp-channel
- [How can I transfer assets using XCM?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-can-i-transfer-assets-using-xcm/38#38)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix. Parachain account needs ROC on rococo-local Relaychain.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i added 5 ROC to the sovereign account of my parachain on Rococo but still FailedToTransact

Comment: How did you solve it @Decentration?

Answer (score 2):

The cause for the error could also be because you are funding the wrong sovereign account of the sending parachain. I used [this](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate-js-utilities/) tool to convert the `ParaId to Address`, yet I forgot to switch the `child` toggle to `sibling`.

I didn't know the sovereign account (address) of a parachain is different on the relay chain (`child`) then on a parachain (`sibling`).

For more information check out [this answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/how-to-calculate-sovereignaccount-for-parachain/1210)