# How to fix the `FailedToTransactAsset("InsufficientBalance")` error?

Tags: xcm, balances, xcmp, transact, insufficient

I already read this post [XCM cross-chain transfer error FailedToTransactAsset("InsufficientBalance")?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/xcm-cross-chain-transfer-error-failedtotransactassetinsufficientbalance) , but nothing helped.

I get the following XCM logs (originates from Parachain 2001):

```
2023-11-02 05:35:24.357 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::origin_conversion: [Parachain] SovereignSignedViaLocation origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) }, kind: Superuser    
2023-11-02 05:35:24.357 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::origin_conversion: [Parachain] RelayChainAsNative origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) }, kind: Superuser    
2023-11-02 05:35:24.357 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::origin_conversion: [Parachain] SiblingParachainAsNative origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) }, kind: Superuser    
2023-11-02 05:35:24.357 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::origin_conversion: [Parachain] SignedAccountId32AsNative origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) }, kind: Superuser    
2023-11-02 05:35:24.357 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::convert_origin: [Parachain] could not convert: origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) }, kind: Superuser    
2023-11-02 05:35:24.357 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Parachain] FixedWeightBounds message: Xcm([DescendOrigin(X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] })), WithdrawAsset(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(GeneralKey { length: 2, data: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }) }), fun: Fungible(10000000000000) }])), BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(GeneralKey { length: 2, data: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }) }), fun: Fungible(10000000000000) }, weight_limit: Unlimited }, LockAsset { asset: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(GeneralKey { length: 2, data: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }) }), fun: Fungible(10000000000) }, unlocker: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X2(Parachain(2000), AccountId32 { network: None, id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) } }])    
2023-11-02 05:35:24.357 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit: [Parachain] origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) }, message: Xcm([DescendOrigin(X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] })), WithdrawAsset(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(GeneralKey { length: 2, data: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }) }), fun: Fungible(10000000000000) }])), BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(GeneralKey { length: 2, data: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }) }), fun: Fungible(10000000000000) }, weight_limit: Unlimited }, LockAsset { asset: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(GeneralKey { length: 2, data: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }) }), fun: Fungible(10000000000) }, unlocker: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X2(Parachain(2000), AccountId32 { network: None, id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) } }]), weight_credit: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-11-02 05:35:24.357 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::barriers: [Parachain] TakeWeightCredit origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) }, instructions: [DescendOrigin(X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] })), WithdrawAsset(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(GeneralKey { length: 2, data: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }) }), fun: Fungible(10000000000000) }])), BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(GeneralKey { length: 2, data: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }) }), fun: Fungible(10000000000000) }, weight_limit: Unlimited }, LockAsset { asset: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(GeneralKey { length: 2, data: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }) }), fun: Fungible(10000000000) }, unlocker: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X2(Parachain(2000), AccountId32 { network: None, id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) } }], max_weight: <wasm:stripped>, properties: Properties { weight_credit: <wasm:stripped>, message_id: None }    
2023-11-02 05:35:24.357 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::process: [Parachain] origin: Some(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) }), total_surplus/refunded: <wasm:stripped>/<wasm:stripped>, error_handler_weight: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-11-02 05:35:24.357 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::process_instruction: [Parachain] === DescendOrigin(X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }))    
2023-11-02 05:35:24.358 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::process_instruction: [Parachain] === WithdrawAsset(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(GeneralKey { length: 2, data: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }) }), fun: Fungible(10000000000000) }]))      
2023-11-02 05:35:24.359 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute: [Parachain] !!! ERROR: FailedToTransactAsset("InsufficientBalance")    
2023-11-02 05:35:24.359 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit: [Parachain] result: Err(ExecutorError { index: 1, xcm_error: FailedToTransactAsset("InsufficientBalance"), weight: <wasm:stripped> })    
2023-11-02 05:35:24.359 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Parachain] FixedRateOfFungible::refund_weight weight: <wasm:stripped>, context: XcmContext { origin: Some(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X2(Parachain(2000), AccountId32 { network: None, id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) }), message_id: [143, 158, 177, 103, 122, 233, 162, 35, 234, 11, 70, 43, 39, 79, 250, 6, 104, 7, 82, 112, 172, 195, 84, 137, 36, 29, 174, 18, 82, 246, 144, 80], topic: None }    
2023-11-02 05:35:24.359 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Parachain] FixedRateOfFungible::refund_weight weight: <wasm:stripped>, context: XcmContext { origin: Some(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X2(Parachain(2000), AccountId32 { network: None, id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) }), message_id: [143, 158, 177, 103, 122, 233, 162, 35, 234, 11, 70, 43, 39, 79, 250, 6, 104, 7, 82, 112, 172, 195, 84, 137, 36, 29, 174, 18, 82, 246, 144, 80], topic: None }    
2023-11-02 05:35:24.359 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Parachain] FixedRateOfFungible::refund_weight weight: <wasm:stripped>, context: XcmContext { origin: Some(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X2(Parachain(2000), AccountId32 { network: None, id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) }), message_id: [143, 158, 177, 103, 122, 233, 162, 35, 234, 11, 70, 43, 39, 79, 250, 6, 104, 7, 82, 112, 172, 195, 84, 137, 36, 29, 174, 18, 82, 246, 144, 80], topic: None }    
2023-11-02 05:35:24.359 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Parachain] AssetRegistryTrader::refund_weight weight: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-11-02 05:35:24.359 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit: [Parachain] Execution errored at 1: FailedToTransactAsset("InsufficientBalance") (original_origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) })
```

My setup is the following:

- local rococo relaychain
- parachain 2000
- parachain 2001

I send the following encoded call data XCM message from parachain 2000 to parachain 2001 as the well-known Alice account as a normal signed origin:

```
0x490003010100451f030c000400000106020001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b00a0724e18091300000106020001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b00a0724e1809002700000106020001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000700e40b5402010200411f0100d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
```

[image]

I funded the sovereign account of para id 2000 and 2001 and the sibling account of parachain id 2000 and 2001 on the rococo-local relaychain.

I am currently trying out the `LockAsset` functionality and what I noticed is that the well known Alice account is different on the receiving chain after sending it through XCM. It is: `[212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125]`, which translates to `0x003593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da200` (using substrate utilities https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate-js-utilities/ represented as account id `5C4ymnPah145YenQ6EAUCrt6ZssKz15hVuLMGNVxNKhDtrP2` on para 2001). Although the Alice account has the account id `5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY`, which should be `0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d` in hex (`[0,212,53,147,199,21,253,211,28,97,20,26,189,4,169,159,214,130,44,133,88,133,76,205,227,154,86,132,231,165,109,162,125]` u8 byte array).

So my inner question is: Which account has to be funded with how much of what curreny to fix the `InsufficientBalance` error?

Side fact: I am using the following XCM configuration:

Here is the full version: https://pastebin.com/7242tXkA

```rust
pub const MY_KEY: &[u8] = &[0, 1];

    pub const NoneNetwork: Option<NetworkId> = None;

...

pub fn vec_to_fixed_array<const S: usize>(src: Vec<u8>) -> [u8; S] {
    let mut dest = [0; S];
    let len = min(src.len(), S);
    dest[..len].copy_from_slice(&src.as_slice()[..len]);

    dest
}

pub fn general_key(data: &[u8]) -> Junction {
    GeneralKey {
        length: data.len().min(32) as u8,
        data: vec_to_fixed_array(data.to_vec()),
    }
}
...

/// Means for transacting assets on this chain.
pub type MultiAssetTransactor = MultiCurrencyAdapter<
    // All known Assets will be processed by the following MultiCurrency implementation.
    Currencies,
    // Any unknown Assets will be processed by the following UnknownAsset implementation.
    (),
    // This means that this adapter should handle any token that `AssetConvert` can convert
    // using Currencies and UnknownTokens in all other cases.
    IsNativeConcrete<AssetId, AssetConvert>,
    // Our chain's account ID type (we can't get away without mentioning it explicitly).
    AccountId,
    // Convert an XCM `MultiLocation` into a local account id.
    LocationToAccountId,
    // The AssetId that corresponds to the native currency.
    AssetId,
    // Struct that provides functions to convert `Asset` <=> `MultiLocation`.
    AssetConvert,
    // In case of deposit failure, known assets will be placed in treasury.
    DepositToAlternative<RootAccount, Currencies, AssetId, AccountId, Balance>,
>;

...

/// Type for specifying how a `MultiLocation` can be converted into an `AccountId`. This is used
/// when determining ownership of accounts for asset transacting and when attempting to use XCM
/// `Transact` in order to determine the dispatch Origin.
pub type LocationToAccountId = (
    // The parent (Relay-chain) origin converts to the default `AccountId`.
    ParentIsPreset<AccountId>,
    // Sibling parachain origins convert to AccountId via the `ParaId::into`.
    SiblingParachainConvertsVia<polkadot_parachain_primitives::primitives::Sibling, AccountId>,
    // If we receive a MultiLocation of type AccountKey20, just generate a native account
    AccountId32Aliases<NoneNetwork, AccountId>,
    // Generate remote accounts according to polkadot standards
    staging_xcm_builder::HashedDescription<
        AccountId,
        staging_xcm_builder::DescribeFamily<staging_xcm_builder::DescribeAllTerminal>,
    >,
);

...


/// This is the type we use to convert an (incoming) XCM origin into a local `Origin` instance,
/// ready for dispatching a transaction with Xcm's `Transact`. There is an `OriginKind` which can
/// biases the kind of local `Origin` it will become.
pub type XcmOriginToTransactDispatchOrigin = (
    // Sovereign account converter; this attempts to derive an `AccountId` from the origin location
    // using `LocationToAccountId` and then turn that into the usual `Signed` origin. Useful for
    // foreign chains who want to have a local sovereign account on this chain which they control.
    SovereignSignedViaLocation<LocationToAccountId, RuntimeOrigin>,
    // Native converter for Relay-chain (Parent) location; will convert to a `Relay` origin when
    // recognised.
    RelayChainAsNative<RelayChainOrigin, RuntimeOrigin>,
    // Native converter for sibling Parachains; will convert to a `SiblingPara` origin when
    // recognised.
    SiblingParachainAsNative<cumulus_pallet_xcm::Origin, RuntimeOrigin>,
    // Native signed account converter; this just converts an `AccountId32` origin into a normal
    // `RuntimeOrigin::Signed` origin of the same 32-byte value.
    SignedAccountId32AsNative<NoneNetwork, RuntimeOrigin>,
    // Xcm origins can be represented natively under the Xcm pallet's Xcm origin.
    XcmPassthrough<RuntimeOrigin>,
);

...

/// Convert an incoming `MultiLocation` into a `Asset` if possible.
/// Here we need to know the canonical representation of all the tokens we handle in order to
/// correctly convert their `MultiLocation` representation into our internal `Asset` type.
impl Convert<MultiLocation, Option<AssetId>> for AssetConvert {
    fn convert(location: MultiLocation) -> Option<AssetId> {
        if location == MultiLocation::parent() {
            return Some(1u32);
        }

        match location {
            MultiLocation {
                parents: 0,
                interior: X1(GeneralKey { data, length }),
            } => {
                let key = &data[..data.len().min(length as usize)];
                if key == MY_KEY {
                    return Some(0u32);
                }

                None
            }
            MultiLocation {
                parents: 1,
                interior: X2(Parachain(para_id), GeneralKey { data, length }),
            } => {
                let key = &data[..data.len().min(length as usize)];
                if para_id == u32::from(ParachainInfo::parachain_id()) && key == MY_KEY {
                    return Some(0u32);
                }

                AssetRegistry::location_to_asset_id(location)
            }
            _ => AssetRegistry::location_to_asset_id(location),
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

`0x76f80ba707bc6d37e0a1403c995b3cba9d424ed6ab87262b0e9a30d5dc5822c5`

I am already figuring this out for 3 days.. It does not make any sense and I would really love some help now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Maybe you should pass `212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125` to the [substrate utils](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate-js-utilities/), the result is `0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d`, it's Alice
2. This location conversion was failed. [AccountId32Aliases](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/polkadot-v1.2.0/polkadot/xcm/xcm-builder/src/location_conversion.rs#L325) got `None` when `withdraw_asset` who is {parents: 1, ...}, so it want transfer from None address, failed. Why parents:1? [WithComputedOrigin](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/polkadot-v1.1.0/polkadot/xcm/xcm-builder/src/barriers.rs#L202) change the origin.

My test log

```
xcm::currency_adapter: [Parachain] withdraw_asset what: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(PalletInstance(5)) }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000000) }, who: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X2(Parachain(2105), AccountKey20 { network: Some(Rococo), key: [192, 240, 244, 171, 50, 76, 70, 229, 93, 2, 208, 3, 51, 67, 180, 190, 138, 85, 83, 45] }) }
```

You cannot let someone claiming to be Alice from parachain X use the Alice account in parachain Y. That would put your chain at risk, as parachain X can claim to be a descended origin of any account.

Track here https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/2130

Comment: I tried this again. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. So the account is funded with that balance and more already.

Comment: Could you provide your repo?

Comment: Unfortunately I won't post the repo (because it's in private stealth mode for multiple reasons), but I will post my full xcm configuration: https://pastebin.com/7242tXkA

Comment: However, I am 100% sure that the `pallet-balances` emits this error. So I can exclude the case of `oml-tokens` emitting this error. It can still be `orml-currencies (Currencies)`, though.

Comment: @Chralt Follow here: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/2130

Answer (score 1):

> You cannot let someone claiming to be Alice from parachain X use the Alice account in parachain Y. That would put your chain at risk, as parachain X can claim to be a descended origin of any account. And that is what Account32Aliases prevents by checking that parents is 0 (i.e., in order to use Alice account in parachain Y the message should have been originated in parachain Y).

> You can use the convertor HashedDescription, which will hash the descended multilocation and give you a fresh new account that Alice from parachain X will be able to control in parachain Y