# Is teleport of ROC from Rockmine to my parachain should be used instead of reserve transfer?

Tags: xcm, xcmp, statemine, test-network, teleport

I am trying to `polkadotXcm.reserveTransferAssets` of ROC on from Rockmine to Dali https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-rockmine-rpc.polkadot.io#/extrinsics/decode/0x1f02010101009d2001000101002aa47c41b763a16946b6cc7e051174877b14fafe5d8daf075b0e39e2398c8e4c010400010000070088526a7400000000  .

It fails on client side with with`polkadotXcm.UnweighableMessage` from Rococo node. There is no field in `reserveTransferAssets` to set weight. And message is not sent at all.

When I use `polkadotXcm.teleportAssets`  https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-rockmine-rpc.polkadot.io#/extrinsics/decode/0x1f01010101009d2001000101002aa47c41b763a16946b6cc7e051174877b14fafe5d8daf075b0e39e2398c8e4c010400010000070088526a7400000000  message reaches our parachain. But it is not configured to receive teleport assets.

Should we receive teleports from Rockmine? What would be origin? Is planned to have Statemine also use Teleport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use `reserve_transfer`, because `teleport` requires both the source and destination of have a high level of mutual trust. Details can be found [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-can-i-transfer-assets-using-xcm/38#38).

About `UnweighableMessage`, I think there may be a bug in statemint runtime 9290 and it's ok in RT9220. Please wait for my debugging results for specific reasons, and I will update the answer soon.

---

Well, some prs related to `UnweighableMessage` :

1. https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/1454
2. https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/1629

Focus on this line: https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/1629/files#diff-ba0e9507c93c11e6a5cc354264540f9fab51dcaf97cfe7e28aebf08bb8c915f8R60

```
// Currently there is no trusted reserve
fn reserve_asset_deposited(_assets: &MultiAssets) -> XCMWeight {
    u64::MAX
}
```

This will make the weight of the `reserve_asset_deposited` instruction fail on [`check_add`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.29/xcm/xcm-builder/src/weight.rs#L97) due to **u64 overflow**. And then `UnweighableMessage`.

---

However, **you could use `limited_reserve_transfer_assets`** instead of `reserve_transfer_assets` to avoid this error. Because it will not call weigher to compute the weight [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.29/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L796).

like this: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-rockmine-rpc.polkadot.io#/extrinsics/decode/0x1f08010101009d2001000101002aa47c41b763a16946b6cc7e051174877b14fafe5d8daf075b0e39e2398c8e4c010400010000070088526a740000000000

Comment: ok. will check version mentioned

Comment: i did transfers previosly. but they kind of stopped to work.

Comment: transfer from rococo to rockmine does not work for me too. but teleport work perfectly.

Comment: rockmine is in full 100% trust with rococo as rockmine accepts rococo as root.

Comment: but yeah, it is unclear. it should teleport to rococo, but then transfer to our chain for parachain xcm.

Comment: Updated @DzmitryLahoda

Comment: likely transfering from my chain to relay not works either https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.composablefinance.ninja#/extrinsics/decode/0x29080101000100010100b8e39e87c0fec96f7d012d31a4c27b44bfb504ab359662112e4270e380c84341010400000000070010a5d4e8000000000102286bee will retry later

Comment: It seems you shouldn't use asset `{0, here}`, if it's not related to this question, you could open a new question and I would help you.

Comment: i tried 1 too. let me compare with what is on picasso and on otber chains. and if the root cause is different.

Answer (score 1):

`reserveTransferAssets` is okay. That's not the root cause `UnweighableMessage`.

Check the [documentation](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/9d4e1a18b30885af52ae655d2df9a05e041ee88d/xcm/src/v2/mod.rs#L48-L51).

You should set a reasonable weight. Otherwise, the call will fail.

---

[`reserve_transfer_assets`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/9d4e1a18b30885af52ae655d2df9a05e041ee88d/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L549)  will call the [`do_reserve_transfer_assets`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/9d4e1a18b30885af52ae655d2df9a05e041ee88d/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L781) internally with the weight `None`. Then it will enter [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/9d4e1a18b30885af52ae655d2df9a05e041ee88d/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L820-L821). So, check the `Weighter`. IIUC, "you should set a reasonable weighter in `runtime/lib.rs`".

Comment: downvoted. because there is not weight in reserveTransferAssets

Comment: please read the docs too - in both cases it will fail either teleport or reserve transfer, so why one fails and other works if these are same?

Comment: Updated. Check the answer again.