# Clarification needed in substrate xcm docs

Tags: parachain, xcm, xcmp

I am trying to send funds from parachain B (1001) to parachain A, but the [substrate docs](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/transfer-assets-with-xcm/) do not show completely how to transfer to parachain A (1000) (or it could at least be clearer).

In my case parachain b is (2113) and parachain A is (2000).

However, at `DepositAsset instruction` section 5. it says:

*Specify the beneficiary to receive the deposited assets.*

*You can deposit the assets remaining into the sovereign account for parachain A or into a specific account. For this tutorial, the assets are deposited using a specified account address for the previously unfunded account KRIS-PUBS.*

It doesn't explicitly show how to send to Parachain A, either sovereign account or a target account within Parachain A.

1. How do you send to a sovereign account in Parachain A?
2. How do you send to specific account in Parachain A?

For easy replication here is the encoded call data from the docs:

```
0xc1028400da8255623a48e0cff4c515aa835ad22f0f4f4390945e7308f830d09e7ad79e74012a384fe857f14f13bf557a09ed42e4d05b2dad593239b430ae0b0c43a04e5374b5416baf52d182b43dfddd71428d0efd078ba8c3f760194e839b8436ce661781f400500004001f00010100020c000400000000070010a5d4e813000000000700e8764817000d01000400010100c0997c4f2b3a83eb07ef74a867cf672a25a2a30cc61abc936dcc994df77ba84a
```

Please also provide the encoded call data in the docs (or responses) if you can, so the call can be replicated quickly.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Doesn't this help https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-can-i-transfer-assets-using-xcm ?

Comment: the docs can be improved by following through with the basic example in a complete way (with perhaps the two examples requested above) rather than leaving the most important part ambiguous at section 5.

Comment: It would seem to me that this is an issue that is best filed at the substrate docs repo [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/issues/new/choose)

Answer (score 0):

The link you shared was broken, is it clear how to perform the DepositAsset instruction in this link: [DepositAsset instruction](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/transfer-assets-with-xcm/#depositasset-instruction)?

Another example I suggest you to take a look is this [transfer example](https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-docs/blob/main/examples/src/1_transfers/reserve.rs#L11), is a code example where ALICE transfers relay native tokens from parachain A to parachain B.