# Can we modify storages using Cross Chain Message Passing(XCM)?

Tags: polkadot, xcm, substrate-parachain-template, xcmp, xcmv3

I am currently working on transferring NFTs from one chain to another using XCM. To accomplish this, I need to remove the NFTs from the storage of the source chain and add them to the storage of Pallet-nfts present at destination chain. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could provide me with some ideas related to this.

Answer (score 1):

The `Transact` instruction allows for the execution of calls (from a RuntimeCall in a FRAME-based system, to a smart contract function call in an EVM-based system) in a consensus system. With this you can modify storage of another chain with a XCM transaction.

The perfect example you can look at is this: [transact_mint_nft](https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-docs/blob/main/examples/src/3_transact/mod.rs#L54) from the XCM Docs, that shows you how the parachain A creates a NFT Collection and mint an NFT on the relay chain.

To understand transfers read this [How can I transfer assets using XCM?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-can-i-transfer-assets-using-xcm).

And for examples of NFT transfers you can take a look in the examples of the **XCM simulator**: [teleport_nft](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.42/xcm/xcm-simulator/example/src/lib.rs#L338C5-L338C17) and [reserve_asset_transfer_nft](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.42/xcm/xcm-simulator/example/src/lib.rs#L404).