# Differences using xcm V2 or V3

Tags: polkadot, xcm

What are the differences while using `XCM V2` or `V3`? For example if I want to send DOT from Polkadot to `Astar`. Do I have to pay less fee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XCM V3 version offers an expanded set of instructions compared to V2. Among the new instructions are:

- UnpaidExecution
- LockAsset
- UnlockAsset
- Burn Asset
- NoteUnlockable

Additionally, there are several other instructions available in the XCM V3 version, providing even greater functionality and versatility.

For transferring assets you can check it [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-can-i-transfer-assets-using-xcm) and approximately same amount of fees is deducted in both V2 and V3